# how to vectorize this program

Tags: c++, eigen

The program below (well, the lines after "from here") is a construct i have to use a lot. 
I was wondering whether it is possible (eventually using functions from the eigen library) 
to vectorize or otherwise make this program run faster.

Essentially, given a vector of `float` `x`, this construct has recover the indexes 
of the sorted elements of `x` in a `int` vector `SIndex`. For example, if the first 
entry of `SIndex` is 10, it means that the 10th element of `x` was the smallest element 
of `x`.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;
using namespace std;

typedef pair<int, float> sortData;
bool sortDataLess(const sortData& left, const sortData& right){
    return left.second<right.second;
}

int main(){
    int n=20,i;
    float LO=-1.0,HI=1.0;
    srand (time(NULL));
    vector<float> x(n);
    vector<float> y(n);
    vector<int> SIndex(n);  
    vector<sortData> foo(n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) x[i]=LO+(float)rand()/((float)RAND_MAX/(HI-LO));
    //from here:
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) foo[i]=sortData(i,x[i]);
    sort(foo.begin(),foo.end(),sortDataLess);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        sortData bar=foo[i];
        y[i]=x[bar.first];
        SIndex[i]=bar.first;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) std::cout << SIndex[i] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is fundamentally a sorting problem, and vectorization is not particularly good at sorts. So it's *possible*, but it may not be faster.

Comment: thanks for the hint. Can you post it as an answer? Also, I was wondering if one could use some eigen functions as a substitute to the last loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no getting around the fact that this is a sorting problem, and vectorization doesn't necessarily improve sorts very much. For example, the partition step of quicksort can do the comparison in parallel, but it then needs to select and store the 0–*n* values that passed the comparison. This can absolutely be done, but it starts throwing out the advantages you get from vectorization—you need to convert from a comparison mask to a shuffle mask, which is probably a lookup table (bad), and you need a variable-sized store, which means no alignment (bad, although [maybe not that bad](http://lemire.me/blog/archives/2012/05/31/data-alignment-for-speed-myth-or-reality/)). Mergesort needs to merge two sorted lists, which in *some* cases could be improved by vectorization, but in the worst case (I think) needs the same number of steps as the scalar case.

And, of course, there's a decent chance that any major speed boost you get from vectorization will have already been done inside your standard library's `std::sort` implementation. To get it, though, you'd need to be sorting primitive types with the default comparison operator.

If you're worried about performance, you can easily avoid the last loop, though. Just sort a list of indices using your float array as a comparison:

```
struct IndirectLess {
    template <typename T>
    IndirectLess(T iter) : values(&*iter) {}

    bool operator()(int left, int right)
    {
        return values[left] < values[right];
    }

    float const* values;
};

int main() {
    // ...
    std::vector<int> SIndex;
    SIndex.reserve(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        SIndex.push_back(n);

    std::sort(SIndex.begin(), SIndex.end(), IndirectLess(x.begin()));
    // ...
}
```

Now you've *only* produced your list of sorted indices. You have the potential to lose some cache locality, so for really big lists it *might* be slower. At that point it might be possible to vectorize your last loop, depending on the architecture. It's just data manipulation, though—read four values, store 1st and 3rd in one place and 2nd and 4th in another—so I wouldn't expect Eigen to help much at that point.

Comment: thanks: i really like this alternative construct, i find it much more elegant than what i was using.